# chance for re-using oracle database after system migration?

Tags: oracle, oracleforms

I have an ERP application running with Oracle forms and Oracle database. Now I am planning to migrate this application to a java based enterprise application. will it be a good idea to keep the existing oracle database as back end and developing a web application with certain level of changes/additions in the DB design.

Answer (score 0):

There are two facts to know before answer your questions:

1. has your database schema some oracle forms special structures or is it in 3rd normal form and simply stores data using keys and enforced referential integrity?
2. How much stored code contains your database?

Ad 1. Oracle forms don't have specific schema reqiurements. They work best if your schema if based on 3rd normal form. If your schema is like this, use it for new Java application. We have both forms and Java EE applications on same database schemas and is works fine.

Advantage is, if you have keys (primary, unique, foreign) in your schema. Use them when generating Java app.

Probably you will have to add @Version columns for optimistic locking (see https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/Version.html). But there is not reason to build new schema for it.

Ad 2. Your will have to overwrite bigger part of database stored code (triggers, procedures, functions) to Java. In most cases this does not have dramatic impact to schema structure, but deal with it.

So - if your database schema is not tailored to some UI client needs AND you want only use a new client, use your schema. If not, create a new one.